# writing file Filewriter.write(blob) windows10

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-10, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

the cordova-plugin-file that I use for my ios application does not support `FileWriter.write(blob)` on windows10.

After looking for an alternative, I really can't find anything.
Any ideas how to tackle this issue?

Thx in advance